# How does XMLHttpRequest behave onClose of browser?

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, browser, xmlhttprequest

What can I expect if I initiate an XMLHttpRequest when the onClose event of the tab or browser   window is fired? What happens if the XMLHttpRequest takes too long? Will the request be aborted or cut short as the window closes? Is there a guarantee that the request will be allowed to run it's natural course (and terminate with time out, 200, 303, 404 or 500)?

Will using jQuery make any difference?

I am unable simulate a slow connection to test this out on a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never be *guaranteed* that any request will complete, and this case is no exception.

You might have better luck with either the `onunload` or [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/beforeunload) events, especially the latter.

Comment: That is not what I meant by "guaranteed". I would like to know if AJAX request will be cut short by a closing window? Or will it allow the request to complete (even if it completes with a timeout or 404, 303 or 500). Should I rephrase my question?

Comment: I understood what you meant :) The browser will not wait for your AJAX request to complete.  It may or may not succeed within the time it has.  I believe you'll have better luck with onbeforeunload than onclose.  You may also have better luck injecting an image tag into the page instead of using XHR.  Hope this helps!